# Insight of a theorem on Homomorphisms of modules: what should we understand?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

I came across the following theorem in homomorphisms of modules, which I couldn't understand beyond symbolic and set theoretic verifications.

> Let $M$ be a left $R$-module and $G$ an abelian group. Then $\rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,G)$ is a left $R$-module via the right $R$-module structure of $R$. Then there is an isomorphism of abelian groups 
>   $$\rm{Hom}_R(M,\rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,G))\rightarrow \rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M,G).$$

My obvious question is what should we understand from this isomorphism? Another question is, at what places such situations occurs? I mean, can one illustrate this theorem with some special case or example?

Comment: A better way (in my opinion) of writing this isomorphism is to think of $M$ on the RHS as $R \otimes_R M$ (i.e. $\mathrm{Hom}_R(M, \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R, G)) \simeq \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R \otimes_R M, G)$). Then the statement is just a particular case of the [tensor-hom adjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor-hom_adjunction). This viewpoint 1) basically introduces what the tensor product is (if one hasn't seen it before), and 2) can explain where the isomorphism above comes from (if one has seen the tensor product before).

Comment: The structure on the left also arises in many proofs of the fact that the category of modules over a ring $R$ carries enough injectives.